# sphinx add a page break in my pdf with latexpdf?

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I generate a documentation from rst to pdf with latexpdf and sphinx.

How can I add some page break (=new page) in my PDF?

For now I use PageBreak but it only work with rst2pdf.

```
.. raw:: pdf

   PageBreak
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use raw latex.

```
.. raw:: latex

    \newpage
```

Answer (score 12):

Maybe a slightly better solution, which also "flushes" all pending floats:

```
.. raw:: latex

    \clearpage
```

Answer (score 0):

When using [myst-parser](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) you can use:

````
    ```{rst-eval}
    .. raw:: latex
  
        \newpage
    ```
````

first to break out of md. The second as an interpretation in latex.

Comment: Note that the "myst" parser parses *Markdown* while the OP is flagged as "restructuredtext".

Comment: True. But since the headline isn't explicit this is still a valid result for me. But yes, its kind of out there.